# Is it possible to use blockchain with realm database for a Android app

Tags: blockchain, realm-mobile-platform

I am building this Android app with realm database. I have read about blockchain too. I couldn't find any information with those 2 concepts together. I just want to know if it is possible to incorporate blockchain with Android and realm. Thank you

Comment: You probably can, but it doesn’t mean you should. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just trying to develop a inventory management system. Can you share some tutorials if you happen to have any